# Numpy: difference between array of shape (N, 3) and array of shape (M, 3), where M < 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of `A` of shape `(N, 3)` and an array B of shape `(M, 3)`, where `M < N`.

I want to create some kind of array shape `C` of shape `(M, N, 3)`, where `C[i, :, :]` of shape `(3 ,N)` is the difference between all points in `A` and the `ith` point of `B`:

```py
C[i, :, :] == A - B[i]
```

Orr more explicitly:

```py
C[i, :, :] == A[:, :] - B[i, :]
```

What is the best way to do it easily with vectorized `Numpy` operations, without having to rely on loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast:

```
C = A[None] - B[:, None]
```

Shapes:

```
# A[None].shape
(1, N, 3)

# B[:,None].shape
(M, 1, 3)

# C.shape
(M, N, 3)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [numpy's broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```py
C = (A[None] - B[:, None])
```